# How to re-create the Facebook "inline popup" inside of text while typing, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

While typing into a textarea, I'd like certain character combinations to trigger an inline, popup "select box", just like in Facebook when you tag your friends in posts/comments.

For example, if the user were to type `[friend:m` they'd get a popup, with a list of their friends that start with m. As they continued typing, they'd get more narrow results... just like auto-complete.

I'd like to have other triggers too... `[place:` or `[info:` , etc...

I've been able to get up to where I can detect the triggers, but not experienced enough with Js/jQuery to finish this off. ;(

Here's what I've got:

```
var totalcount=0;

$('#Data').keyup(function (){
    var arr = $(this).val().split(" ");
    var matchitems = count('[place:', arr);

    if(matchitems > totalcount) {
        $('#Data').val($('#Data').val()+'foobar');
        totalcount = matchitems;
    }
    if(matchitems < totalcount) {
        totalcount = matchitems;
    }
});

function count(value, array) {
    var j=0;
    for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == "[place:") {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

This works, when I type `[place:` it appends "foobar" to textarea. Now I'm trying to take it further; to read the trigger, and then do a JSON call to create the popup list. How do I go about doing this? Know of any tutorials out there that cover this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the behavior you're looking for

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/scM5M/)

I've actually done something similar, I modified it to fit what you're trying to do.

- It looks for a matching `[type:` where type is `friend`, `place`, `info` etc
- Loads the results
- Handles up/down keys to toggle between results, enter to select (or mouse click), esc hides the auto complete results
- Sets the input value based on selection made from auto complete

Comment: Wow, jsfiddle is awesome! Thanks for sharing that code. I think that meets everything I need!

Comment: mdmullinax: one thing, is there a way to completely replace the [type: text with the returned value?

Comment: change `$data.val($data.val().match(/\[\w+:/)[0] + $autocomplete.find('.selected h3').text());` to `$data.val($autocomplete.find('.selected h3').text());` for just the returned value